# Parsing through an xml

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, google-apps-script

I'm trying to parse through an xml file in adwords :

```
<items xmlns:c="http:/example.com" xmlns:g="example.com">
  <item>
    <g:id>123</g:id>
    <g:title>
      <MYNAME]>
    </g:title>
  </item>
```

I'm using this bit of code

```js
    var document2= XmlService.parse(xml);

    var root = document2.getRootElement();

    var Elements= root.getChildren();

    for (var j = 1; j < Elements.length; j++) {

       Logger.log (Elements[j].getChild('g:id');
    }
```

But the error return a null as opposed to 'g:id'
What should I do?

Comment: What language do you use C# C++?

Comment: I'm using javascript in adwords

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service) from Apps Script, specifically the method [getChild(name, namespace)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element?hl=en#getChild%28String,Namespace%29) as follows:

```js
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
function testXML() {
  var xml = '<items xmlns:c="http://example.com" xmlns:g="example.com"><item><g:id>123</g:id><g:title>MYNAME</g:title></item></items>';
  var g_namespace = XmlService.getNamespace('g', 'example.com');
  var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
  var Elements = document.getRootElement().getChildren();
  for (var element = 0, len = Elements.length; element < len; element++) {
    Logger.log(Elements[element].getChild('id', g_namespace).getValue());
  }
}
```